# Error during installation Node.js on Centos 5: GYP is needed by package

Tags: node.js, node-gyp

I'm trying to install NODE.JS on Centos 5 via package manager as described in https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Installing-Node.js-via-package-manager

But unfortunately, during the "yum install nodejs-compat-symlinks npm" I get error message:

```
node-gyp-0.3.5-1.el5.centos.noarch from nodejs-stable has depsolving problems
--> Missing Dependency: gyp is needed by package node-gyp-0.3.5-1.el5.centos.noarch (nodejs-stable)
Error: Missing Dependency: gyp is needed by package node-gyp-0.3.5-1.el5.centos.noarch (nodejs-stable)
```

How can I solve this issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Same problem here, only with CentOS 6.2

The problem lies with the npm package. Just proceed as documented in the README

```
wget http://nodejs.tchol.org/repocfg/el/nodejs-stable-release.noarch.rpm
yum localinstall --nogpgcheck nodejs-stable-release.noarch.rpm
```

And avoid listing npm in this statement

```
yum install nodejs-compat-symlinks
```

You can install npm later with the following statement.

```
curl http://npmjs.org/install.sh | sh
```

Comment: I'm also having this problem, and even the curl http://npmjs.org/install.sh | sh don't work. Any idea how I can install GYP on RHEL 5? I tried to search but can't find anything, and GYP also isn't available on yum